# Convert NSDate to NSString to save in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsdate

I'm very new to iOS programming (as you can probably tell from my code) and I'm having difficulties. My app is a questionnaire with many ViewControllers, each ViewController has a question. The answers to these questions get stored in a NSMutableArray. I then present the answers on the last view, a UITableView. Everything works fine apart from displaying the date in the tableview. I get this error message:

```
2013-12-16 14:04:48.609 Questionnaire[4602:70b] -[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ac5160
2013-12-16 14:04:48.613 Questionnaire[4602:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDate length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ac5160'
```

My array looks like this:

```
    2013-12-16 14:04:32.743 Questionnaire[4602:70b] (
    1234,
    "2013-12-16 14:04:24 +0000",
    Yes,
    Internet,
    "Not Applicable",
    No
)
```

As you can see, the date is stored in the default way, although I can't display it on the TableView unless it's converted to NSString.

Here is a picture of my tableview. Note: the date displays "Null" for testing purposes, see code. (I don't have enough rep to attach an image).

[My tableview](http://oi41.tinypic.com/of7bs8.jpg)

I've googled for literally days, tried all sorts of code and I still can't get it to convert before saving to the array. I've tried to display the date on a UITextField from the UIDatePicker, then I was going to save the date from that textfield but no luck. If anyone is able to guide me on how to convert the date to a NSString before it saves to the array, or if there is a better approach to my problem, please help me!

Thanks for reading.

Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSDate *dob = self.datePicker.date;
    NSString *idNum = self.idTextField.text;

    // If data is input to TextField
    if (![self.idTextField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

        NSLog(@"Questionnaire started");

        // Allocate & initialise array
        self.submission = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Insert ID and DoB
        [self.submission insertObject:idNum atIndex:0];
        [self.submission insertObject:dob atIndex:1];


        // Prepare array, insert Null values

        //[self.submission insertObject:@"Null" atIndex:1]; // for testing

        [self.submission insertObject:@"Null" atIndex:2];
        [self.submission insertObject:@"Null" atIndex:3];
        [self.submission insertObject:@"Null" atIndex:4];
        [self.submission insertObject:@"Null" atIndex:5];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.submission);


        Q1ViewController *Q1 = [[Q1ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Q1ViewController" bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"Move to Q1");

        //Pass array to next viewcontroller
        Q1.submission = self.submission;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:Q1 animated:YES];


    } else { //If TextField is empty
        NSLog(@"TextField is empty");

        //Show error alert
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Incomplete Submission"
                                                         message:@"Please enter a User ID and Date of Birth."
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [myAlert show];
    }
}
```

Edit:

Seems like this was an easy solution that I completely missed, thanks to 'ios Learner' this problem has been solved with just a few lines of code! Much appreciated!!

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                          timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                              dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle
                                                              timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
        NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
```

check this code... pass your string to array

Comment: or modify it to you need

Comment: That worked perfectly! I can't believe its only a few lines of code, you have no idea how much trouble I've had with this :P I tried to vote this up but I don't have enough rep, sorry :( Thanks so much for this though!! I'll update the post with your solution :)

Comment: @rosshump You should accept the answer. Click on the white checkmark below the answer's score.

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing that out. I'm new to posting on stackoverflow as you can probably tell, though I regularly come here for help :)